# How to create a fading-out grind background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a grid background that fades out

So far I've tried a conic-gradient background but I'm not sure how to get it to fade out

```
  background:
    conic-gradient(from 90deg at 1px 1px,#0000 90deg,grey 0) 
    0 0/50px 50px;
```

Comment: the simplest is add an additional background-image that has linear-gradient from transparent to white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be add an additional background-image that has `linear-gradient` from transparent to white:

```css
body {
  background:
    linear-gradient(180deg, #FFF0 0%, #FFFF 100%) 0 0 / 100dvw 100dvh,
    conic-gradient(from 90deg at 1px 1px, #8880 90deg, #888F 0) center -1px / 50px 50px;
}
```

or if you use some body height:

```css
* { margin:0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(180deg, #FFF0 0%, #FFFF 100%),
    conic-gradient(from 90deg at 1px 1px, #8880 90deg, #888F 0) center -1px / 50px 50px;
}
```

Comment: TIL you can create a grid pattern with `conic-gradient`. Brilliant.

Comment: @ray https://css-pattern.com/

Comment: @TemaniAfif wohow pretty cool patterns in there! Keep up the amazing work

Answer (score -2):

1. You can Use
   `{ filter: blur(4px); }` 
   reference:
   Here's [a link](https://youtu.be/GeyKccc83U0)!